# Nested queries in sparql with limits

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I currently trying to create a sample of the dbpedia data for a use case i have to present.
My main goal is to ask for 5 five paintings per european artist (and i want to present only two artists per country at the beginning).

The query without the limits is as follows.

```
    PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
    PREFIX dcterms:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
    PREFIX prop:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>
    PREFIX geonames:<http://sws.geonames.org/>
    PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX dbpedia:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    PREFIX geo-ont:<http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>
    PREFIX ourvocab:<http://example.org/>
    prefix foaf:<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

    SELECT DISTINCT ?painting_name ?artist_name ?european_country ?description ?artist_birthday_year
    WHERE {

    ?european_country dcterms:subject category:Countries_in_Europe.
    ?european_country rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Place.

    ?painting prop:artist ?artist.
    ?painting rdfs:label ?painting_name.
    ?painting prop:type dbpedia:Oil_painting.
    ?painting rdfs:comment ?description.

    ?artist foaf:name ?artist_name.
    ?artist rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Artist.
    ?artist prop:placeOfBirth ?european_country.
    ?artist dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?artist_birthday.


     FILTER (lang(?painting_name) = "" || lang(?painting_name) = "en")
     FILTER (lang(?description) = "" || lang(?description) = "en")
     BIND(year(?artist_birthday) AS ?artist_birthday_year)

    }
```

You can run the query here: http://dbpedia.org/sparql
Now, I am stuck because I do not know how to apply the nested limits in my use case.
Thank you very much in beforehand.

Comment: This is similar to a question on answers.semanticweb.com from 2011, [How to limit SPARQL solution group size?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/9842/how-to-limit-sparql-solution-group-size).  The general consensus there seems to be, "this is tough, and you can _sort of_ get it working if you can provide an order on the elements so that you can say, 'give me, e.g., the two _oldest_ artists from each country, and their _largest_ five paintings.'"  (The predicates oldest and largest aren't particularly important there, so long as there's _some_ order .)

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't compare language tags with `=`.  Those should be `langMatches(lang(?variable),"en")`.   However, as discussed in [Is langMatches("","") true, false, or an error?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25434/is-langmatches-true-false-or-an-error), `lang(?var) = ""` is probably the _right_ way to check for empty language tags.

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua.
So, there is no direct way to tackle with this problem (some magic from 1.1 probably?) the way i see it.
The discussion was really helpful and i followed the same methodology, but it seems as dbpedia did not like that because the query time increased! 
I will work also on some alternatives.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Hello Joshua,I think that sparql cannot handle such requests at the moment and it should be loaded in the client.I am not sure if that is totally correct, but this is how i handle it at the moment.