# Exclude results which have the same property and value

Tags: sparql

If I have this data:

```
:a :p :x; a :C .
:b :p :y; a :C . 
:c :p :y; a :C .
:d :q :z; a :C .
:e :p :y; a :C .
```

How to make a SPARQL query to select the first `?s :p :y` and exclude any other.

In other words, how to change this query:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {?s a :C}
```

so that on this data, there should be only two results, `:d` and either `:b` or `:c` or `:e`. It doesn't matter which, as it depends on the order of matching against the pattern, which I guess is outside the control of the query.

Note: I'm simplifying the actual case, where there is a set of patterns, not just ?s a :C, but the idea is, if some matching triples are also linked with `:p`, there should be one result for identical `?o` in the `?s :p ?o` pattern.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but relevant background includes [Nested queries in sparql with limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018518/nested-queries-in-sparql-with-limits), [SPARQL using subquery with limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061096/sparql-using-subquery-with-limit?lq=1), and [selecting limited subquery data with SPARQL 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469353/selecting-limited-subquery-data-with-sparql-1-1).

Comment: Offsite, see http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/9842/how-to-limit-sparql-solution-group-size and http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/696/sparql-query-1-row-per-distinct-variable-value

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks! The second one, 696, is exactly my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by ?p and ?o and then sample from the ?s values in each group:

```sql
select (sample(?s_) as ?s) ?p ?o where {
  ?s_ a :C .
  ?s_ ?p ?o. 

  #-- Filter here is used to exclude the property that was used
  #-- for selecting individuals (?s_ a :C).  In general, this 
  #-- just needs to make sure that the selection criteria aren't 
  #-- the same as what we're grouping on.  If the candidate values
  #-- of ?p are known in advance, this could replaced by 
  #-- `values ?p { :p :q ... }`.
  filter(?p != rdf:type)
}
group by ?p ?o
```

Comment: Now I have a new, particular case, where `?p` is `owl:sameAs`. It works fine but only before inferencing.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  owl:sameAs is probably an unusual case, since if owl:sameAs(x,y), then x and y will end up having all the same properties and values once inference is available.  But I'm not quite clear on what problem you're having.  Can you give an example?

Comment: If owl:sameAs(x,y) and :p(x,z) :p(y,z), I would like when after inferencing I ask for {?s :p z}, to get only x or y, but not both.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov That would be a bit more of a challenge, but it might still be possible. You'd need to have a way to choose a representative individual from each equivalent class, then group on that.  You could do that in a subquery, and then only use those representative individuals in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` to limit the results to only one row:

```
SELECT ?s {
  ?s :p :y .
} LIMIT 1
```

You can use `ORDER BY` to affect the order of the results and thus the resource that will be selected.

Comment: That would work only in a specific case. In the real situation I would have thousands of results. I have clarified the answer with small extension of the example data.