# How to select first N row of each group

Tags: group-by, limit, sparql

I have some data in my triple store like:

```
Subject     Predicate                               Object
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<http://Doc1>        http://purl.org/dc/terms/created       2013                   
<http://Doc1>        http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor   John                
.
.
<http://Doc2>       http://purl.org/dc/terms/created        2014
<http://Doc2>        http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor    David
.
.
<http://Doc3>       http://purl.org/dc/terms/created        2013
<http://Doc3>       http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor    John        
.
.
.
```

I want to select every triple where subject is Doc1:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
    FILTER ( ?subject = <http://Doc1> )
}
```

That was easy! This is my output:

```
Subject     Predicate                               Object
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<http://Doc1>        http://purl.org/dc/terms/created       2013                   
<http://Doc1>       http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor    John    
..
```

And now for each object i want to return first N triples. In fact I want to select N triples where some document was created in 2013 and N triples where contributor is John etc.
I tried to do something like:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?specObject
WHERE {
    <http://Doc1> ?predicate ?specObject.
     ?subject ?predicate ?specObject
}
```

But this query returns every triple where object is 2013 and John. I need just  first five triple for each group. How can I build this query?
Thanks!

Comment: Your running example doesn't make sense, as Doc1 is not a literal but resource, thus, using quotes around is obviously wrong or at least wouldn't return anything as it's not allowed to have literals in subject position of RDF triples. Please edit it to something like :Doc1.

Comment: Doing something like "n per group" is actually pretty tricky in SPARQL, and comes up from time to time.  In general, you can't do it, but in many specific cases, you can.  You might find http://stackoverflow.com/q/27061096/1281433 and some of the other questions and resources it links to helpful.

Comment: @AKSW - You're right! It wasn't good choice to use literal as subject also just for example. I edited it!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, I saw this thread a couple days ago. I was trying to write some query but without success.