# sparql take the first n of r but respect the value of aggregation

Tags: sparql

I asked a question yesterday about how to take the first n value for the values of an variable. The solution giving yesterday works in all situation exception when I have an aggregation, because this is a new scenario in which I not just want the first n item, but i also want them to be ordered according to the aggregation value.

#### The context

I have a user that has liked many items in the past, i want to take the authors that this user has liked and then suggest other items that have the same author.

#### Data

This is the minimum data that I created just for this question. It is so minimul, I couldn't make it smaller because I wanted you to see the aggregation, which is the part that I am asking the question

```
    @prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
    @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    @prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    @prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

    :algorithm1 :hasArtist :artist_anita .
    :book4 :hasArtist :artist_anita .
    :book3 :hasArtist :artist_anita .
    :animalFarm :hasArtist :george_orwell .

    :book5 :hasArtist :artist_anita .
    :book6 :hasArtist :george_orwell.

    :algorithm1 a :RecommendableClass .
    :book4 a :RecommendableClass .
    :book3 a :RecommendableClass .
    :animalFarm a :RecommendableClass .

    :book5 a :RecommendableClass .
    :book6 a :RecommendableClass .

    :ania :likes :book5 , :book6 .

    :user1 :hasRated [ :ratesBy "0.8"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :algorithm1] .

    :user2 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.9"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :algorithm1 ] .

    :user1 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.5"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :book3] .

    :user3 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.6"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :book3] .

    :user2 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.9"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :book4] .

    :user4 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.3"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :book4] .

    :user3 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.9"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :animalFarm] .

    :user5 :hasRated [:ratesBy "0.1"^^xsd:float ; :aboutItem :animalFarm] .
```

#### Query

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.org/rs#>

select ?item (AVG(?ratingValue) as ?averageRatingValue) ?value 
where
{
  { VALUES ?user { :ania }
  ?anotherUser :hasRated [:aboutItem ?item ; :ratesBy ?ratingValue ] .
  {
      SELECT  ?item ?value ?countableProperty
      WHERE
      { 
        VALUES ?user { :ania }
        ?item a :RecommendableClass ;  :hasArtist ?value .
        { 
          SELECT   ?value (count(*) AS ?count)
          WHERE
          { 
            VALUES ?user { :ania }
            ?user :likes [:hasArtist ?value] .
          }
      GROUP BY  ?value
      ORDER BY DESC(?count)
      LIMIT   10
    }
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?user :hasRated ?rating .
      ?rating :aboutItem ?item
    }
  }
  }
    filter (?anotherUser != ?user)
}
}
group by ?item ?value 
having (?averageRatingValue > 0.2)
order by ?value desc(?averageRatingValue)
```

#### The result

[image]

As you see for `Artist_anita` there are three results, and for `geroge_orwell` just one. But I want for each of them just one item. **respecting the value of the average for sure**

could you help?

Comment: From my point of view, at some point it's getting too complex doing everything with SPARQL. What about a client-side solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "respecting the value of the average for sure". There are three rows for artist_anita, so there are three values for average rating value.  How do you want to aggregate those average values?

Comment: @AKSW I am asking to see the possibility to do that in Sparql, it not possible I go to the application level. Plus, it is complex as well to do that in the application level (time consuming), Finally, the answer provided yesterday in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553600/sparql-limit-the-result-for-each-value-of-a-varible is so elegant and easy understandable.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I mean that there are three values for artist_anita, but I want just one value so I should *respect the average* , in other words, I should take the highest value of the average, (so the item `algorithem1` ), and if i wanted to take 2 items for each artist, i should take the two most high value of the average, did you get me please? (i am not asking about how to aggregate, i already did)

Comment: You for each artist, you want the item with the highest average?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor please just a side note, do you think i provided this time a minimum data and minimum query ?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes exactly for each artist, i want the highest average, but sometimes i want the hightest 2 average, sometimes i want the highest 5 aaverage an so one

Comment: @aniadavid  I think it's probably possible to make it smaller, but it's definitely getting better.

Comment: Ok,  so for each artist, you want the top n items ordered by the item's average.  I think my previous answer showed how to do that, but you may need another layer of subquery.  But that's probably getting kind of complex, and it might be better, like aksw suggested, to do this at the application layer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor * for each artist, you want the top n items ordered by the item's average* (Yes exactly) , * you may need another layer of subquery.* (I tried but couldn't ), * it might be better, like aksw suggested, to do this at the application layer* (is this your final suggestion please?) (if yes, I'll start developing on the applicaiton level)

Comment: @AniaDavid Whether it's better to do this at the application layer or in the query is really up to you, and depends on your data and the performance of your endpoint (as well as where you want to put this logic). It's certainly possible in SPARQL, though.  I've added an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor thank for the answer, i am check it, you are definately amazing

Comment: May I ask a question? As you have already asked many many questions  about the same topic, are you doing a research project or what's the overall goal behind?

Comment: @AKSW i am trying to say that if you (as a user ) like an item, i want to suggest *similar items* , but some items are not good for you because maybe they are for female and you are male, and maybe they are expired (like suggest tickets to the event yesterday) and some items you didn't say anything about so i check what the magority of *similar* uses to you like and i suggest to u. it is a research yes

Comment: @AKSW to make it clear more, i already finished developing the same functionality using the already existing appraoches, in other words, using vector space model and collaborative filtering and content-based, but we need to know if The Semantic Web is helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some even simpler sample data:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:artist1 :p
  [ :item :item1 ; :rating 0.3, 0.4 ] ,
  [ :item :item2 ; :rating 0.8, 0.7, 0.9 ] ,
  [ :item :item3 ; :rating 0.9 ] .

:artist2 :p
  [ :item :item2 ; :rating 0.4, 0.45 ] ,
  [ :item :item3 ; :rating 0.1, 0.2 ] ,
  [ :item :item4 ; :rating 0.7 ] .
```

Here's a query that finds items and average ratings for each artist:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?item (avg(?rating) as ?avgRating) ?artist {
  ?artist :p [ :item ?item ; :rating ?rating ] .
}
group by ?artist ?item
```

```
---------------------------------
| item   | avgRating | artist   |
=================================
| :item3 | 0.9       | :artist1 |
| :item2 | 0.8       | :artist1 |
| :item1 | 0.35      | :artist1 |
| :item4 | 0.7       | :artist2 |
| :item2 | 0.425     | :artist2 |
| :item3 | 0.15      | :artist2 |
---------------------------------
```

Now, to get the top *n* items, by avgRating, you'll need another subquery to find out how many items, per artist, had lower average ranking:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?item (count(?item2) as ?rank) ?avgRating ?artist {
  {
    select ?item (avg(?rating) as ?avgRating) ?artist {
      ?artist :p [ :item ?item ; :rating ?rating ] .
    }
    group by ?artist ?item
  }
  {
    select ?item2 (avg(?rating) as ?avgRating2) ?artist {
      ?artist :p [ :item ?item2 ; :rating ?rating ] .
    }
    group by ?artist ?item2
  }
  filter (?avgRating <= ?avgRating2)
}
group by ?item ?artist ?avgRating
```

```
----------------------------------------
| item   | rank | avgRating | artist   |
========================================
| :item3 | 1    | 0.9       | :artist1 |
| :item2 | 2    | 0.8       | :artist1 |
| :item1 | 3    | 0.35      | :artist1 |
| :item4 | 1    | 0.7       | :artist2 |
| :item2 | 2    | 0.425     | :artist2 |
| :item3 | 3    | 0.15      | :artist2 |
----------------------------------------
```

Now you can filter on that to make sure you're just getting the values with rank less than some value:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?item ?avgRating ?artist {
  {
    select ?item (avg(?rating) as ?avgRating) ?artist {
      ?artist :p [ :item ?item ; :rating ?rating ] .
    }
    group by ?artist ?item
  }
  {
    select ?item2 (avg(?rating) as ?avgRating2) ?artist {
      ?artist :p [ :item ?item2 ; :rating ?rating ] .
    }
    group by ?artist ?item2
  }
  filter (?avgRating <= ?avgRating2)
}
group by ?item ?artist ?avgRating
having (count(?item2) <= 2)
```

```
---------------------------------
| item   | avgRating | artist   |
=================================
| :item3 | 0.9       | :artist1 |
| :item2 | 0.8       | :artist1 |
| :item4 | 0.7       | :artist2 |
| :item2 | 0.425     | :artist2 |
---------------------------------
```

It might be better to do this at the application layer, but it's certainly possible in SPARQL.  In principle, this query finds the average rating for each item *twice* (once in the first subquery, and then again in the second subquery), but a good query optimizer will figure out that the two subqueries are identical, except for variable naming, and could compute it just once.

Comment: *but a good query optimizer will figure out that the two subqueries are identical, except for variable naming, and could compute it just once* does fuseki do that optimization please?

Comment: @AniaDavid I don't know.

Comment: kindly why you convert the groyp from ?item ?artist to ?artist ?item ?

Comment: @AniaDavid That doesn't matter.  It probably happened as I was formatting the query.  The order of variables in `group by` doesn't matter.

Comment: I am sorry but I love you, you are amazing, it is working like a charm

Comment: No opens source optimisers that I am aware of use the suggested optimisation , there maybe commercial optimisers that do this but commercial vendors does tend not to talk about the details of their optimisers